# Oscillating version dependencies with pacman packge manager

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, dependencies, pacman

An executable I needed to run required a new version of a the nettle library.

```
error while loading shared libraries: libnettle.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Checked my current version before upgrading: `pacman -Q nettle` returned `nettle 3.5.1-2`

Upgraded nettle `pacman -S nettle` to version `nettle-3.6-1` which provides libnettle.so.8

Re-ran my executable and now it requires the version I upgraded from.

```
error while loading shared libraries: libnettle.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Weird. So I downgraded back to the previous nettle version

```
pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/nettle-3.5.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

ran my executable and now it depends on libnettle.so.8 again!

```
error while loading shared libraries: libnettle.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What did I screw up to cause this?

Answer (score 0):

I did a full system upgrade. Everything works now with no manual intervention needed.

EDIT: The root cause of this is [due to a partial upgrade](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_maintenance#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported) I did on the library (thank you Paul H.)

> Arch Linux is a rolling release distribution. That means when new library versions are pushed to the repositories, the developers and Trusted Users rebuild all the packages in the repositories that need to be rebuilt against the libraries

...

> ... partial upgrades are not supported. Do not use `pacman -Sy package` or any equivalent such as `pacman -Sy` followed by `pacman -S package`. Always upgrade (with `pacman -Syu`) before installing a package.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_maintenance#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported

Comment: This exactly diagnoses and solves the problem, thank you for pointing to this reference. It's wonderful how resilient the arch distribution is to neglect from an inexperienced user.